# Insert function in binary search tree not saving result--pointers

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct, binary-search-tree

I'm working on a binary search tree using the struct:

```
typedef struct int_bst_node {
        int data;
        struct int_bst_node * left;
        struct int_bst_node * right;
} int_bst_node_t;
```

I have it initially set up like this:

```
int_bst_node_t *tree_p = NULL;
```

to make an empty list.

My problem is that my insert function is not saving the result in my tree_p.
It runs, but does not save the result.

```
bool int_bst_insert(int_bst_node_t ** t_p, int n) {
if (*t_p == NULL) {
        int_bst_node_t *tmp_right = NULL;
        int_bst_node_t *tmp_left = NULL;
        int_bst_node_t tmp = {n,tmp_right,tmp_left};
        int_bst_node_t *tmp_ptr = &tmp;
        t_p = &tmp_ptr;
}
else {if (n<(**t_p).data) return (int_bst_insert(&(**t_p).left,n));
      if (n>(**t_p).data) return (int_bst_insert(&(**t_p).right,n));}
return 1;
}
```

As far as I know, using a pointer to something allows it to be modified in the function.

Here I have a pointer to the *tree_p, so I don't see why it is not saving?

Comment: `t_p = &tmp_ptr`. That is just setting a **local** variable. And just as bad, the value being set , `&tmp_ptr`, is also a local variable that ceases to exist when the function exits and hence cannot be used by the caller.

Comment: Solution: `tmp = malloc(...); tmp->... = ...; *t_p= tmp;`

Comment: Thanks guys it all makes sense now